# How to dynamically add a row in a table when user input (postman-style-reactive-table)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How to dynamically add a row when atleast one character in input (like Postman behaves) in header tab.

1) When user enters any single character in `td` of first row then one row 
   should add below. When user deletes  text from first row and when first row's 
   `td` are empty then delete below row.

2) keep track of text enetered in a model for every row input (ie key and 
   value);

3) when user enters any single character in a row in any `td` then checkbox 
  should be checked otherwise not.

### .ts

```
    model =  new Model ('','','',..............);
    tableRow = {
    "key":[{
    'name':'key1',
    'keyInput':""
    }],
    "value":[{
    'name':'value1',
    'keyInput':""
    }]
    }

addRow(event){
    if(event.target.length < 2){
     let data = {
           'name':'key' + (this.tableRow.key.length + 1),
           'keyInput':""
           }
         this.tableRow.key.push(data )
       }else{
        this.tableRow.key.pop();
         }
       }
```

### .html

```
<div class="col-12 table-responsive">
<table class="table">
<thead>
<th>
<td></td>
<td>Key</td>
<td>Value</td>
</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let row of tableRow.key; let i = index;">
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input (keyup)="addRow($event)" [(ngModel)]="model.key" type="text"></td>
<td><input [(ngModel)]="model.value" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is close. The main things that I would modify is to keep track of the key/value/checked state for each row on the row itself, not on some external model. That way each row is self-maintaining and does not have outside side effects that modify other rows (other than the add/remove row, of course).

The other thing I changed is to capture the `(input)` event, rather than the `(keyup)` event. This is to allow for better mobile cut/paste and right click cut/paste support. `(keyup)` will not capture either of those events.

[Working Example Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/postman-style-reactive-table-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Freactive-table.component.ts)

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: "reactive-table",
  template: `
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Selected</th>
          <th>Key</th>
          <th>value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data.rows; let $index = index;">
          <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="row.selected"/></td>
          <td><input [value]="row.key" (input)="handleKeyChange($event, row, $index)" /></td>
          <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.value" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `,
  styles: [`

  `]
})
export class ReactiveTableComponent {
  public data;
  constructor() {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = {
      rows: [
        {
          selected: false,
          key: "",
          value: "",
          oldKey: ""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  handleKeyChange(event, row, rowIndex) {
    var newKey = event.target.value;
    if (newKey !== row.oldKey) {
      row.selected = true;
    }
    if (newKey === "" && rowIndex === this.data.rows.length -2) {
      this.data.rows.pop();
      row.selected = false;
    }
    else if (newKey !== "" && row.oldKey === "" && rowIndex === this.data.rows.length -1) {
      this.data.rows.push({
        selected: false,
        key: "",
        value: "",
        oldKey: ""
      });
    }
    row.oldKey = row.key = newKey;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Madpop Fixed. I forgot I renamed the project - derp. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very rudimentary implementation of what you might want.

component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'stack-solve';
  //defining row of objects and initializing first row with empty values
  //All values entered on the screen are bound to this array
  rows: any[] = [{
    checked:false,
    key:'',
    value:''
  }];

//This function is called on keyup and checks the checkbox on that row and adds new row if the action was on the last row  
checkAndAddRow(i){
    this.rows[i].checked = true;
    if(this.rows.length - 1 == i){//insert new empty row, incase this keyup event was on the last row, you might want to enhance this logic... 
      this.rows.push({
        checked:false,
        key:'',
        value:''
      })
    }

  }
}
```

template:

```
  <div class="col-12 table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <td></td>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index">
          <td><input [checked]="row.checked" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.key" type="text" name="key" (keyup)="checkAndAddRow(i)"></td>
          <td><input [(ngModel)]="row.value" type="text" name="value" (keyup)="checkAndAddRow(i)"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

app.module:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule // need to import FormsModule if you don't have already
  ],
```